# Display images from SQL database on a webpage

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to display images on a webpage, using file paths queried from an SQL database. However, when I follow the link I only see one image (the second in the SQL table) which is incorrectly displayed as an icon and the title. I think the issue is with the echo statement, so could someone have a look? Thanks.

This is the link I follow from the selection page:

```
<a href="index.php?spain_2014">
     <img src="congost.jpg" alt="congost" id="congost">
</a>
```

Then it passes through the controller, index.php:

```
else if(empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) !== true)
   {        
        $gallery_name = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
        $rows = query("SELECT * FROM {$gallery_name}"); 
        render("gallery_template.php", ["title" => "Gallery", "rows" => $rows]);
    }
```

And is rendered in the gallery template:

```
<div id="gallery_images">
        <!-- Gallery -->
        <?php
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                echo("<img src=\"~/vhosts/final_project/public/galleries/" . $row["filepath"] . "/>");
                print($row["title"]);
            } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try using `var_dump($rows)` before you pass it to `render` Do the same again inside the call to `render`

Comment: @Terminus I used var_dump before passing it to render (not sure where to call it inside render), and from the arrays it displayed it seems that it's querying the database correctly: 
array (size=5)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Glow Poi 2' (length=10)
      'filepath' => string 'diwali_fire_show/002.jpg' (length=24)

So it looks like the problem's in the gallery template.

Comment: var_dump  $rows as the first thing in render. If the results are the same before the call and after the call, than something is happening before the while loop. Stick a `var_dump($row);` inside the foreach and see what happens. Be sure you check the source code of the page (press ctrl+u)

Comment: Indeed, the problem is with the foreach loop. I checked the source code and the image filepaths and html is being concatenated together, so it winds up like this in the page src, all along one line: 
<div><img src="../galleries/diwali_fire_show/001.jpg/></div><div><img src="../galleries/diwali_fire_show/002.jpg/></div>    </div>

So my image src becomes `code`"../galleries/diwali_fire_show/001.jpg/></div><div><img src="`code`

Comment: Now you know: never trust what the browser shows you ;)

Comment: Indeed - I spent today playing round with the html and checking the source code, and I am happy to say the images are now displaying :) Thank you very much, Terminus.